# How do I override a 'used' class?

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-7

I am using Laravel 5.8 and I'm attempting to modify a package class from the Vendor directory. To acheive this, I have created a new class which extends the Vendor class, and I can replace the named functions within it- all working great.

However, the original class 'uses' a class, which I have mimicked in my new class, as follows:

```
use VendorName\PackageName\OriginalController

// use VendorName\PackageName\SomeClass as StoreRequest; How can I replace this...
use App\Http\Requests\NewRequestClass as StoreRequest; // ... with this..? (not working)

class NewController extends OriginalController {

    private function somefunction(StoreRequest $request){ // This doesn't work; it is still using the StoreReqest defined in OriginalController
        // ...
    }

}
```

See comments- Is it possible to override this?

Comment: I've never actually tried this, but I suspect you might be able to do this by setting up a custom autoloader to specifically catch when the original class is requested and load in your own file

Comment: Does your `NewRequestClass` extend `StoreRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

Its generally not possible modify/delete class or function. Not without extensions like `Classkit`. But i am not really a fan of this type of code. But you can Check these questions, which might help:

- [Redefining PHP class functions on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998375/redefining-php-class-functions-on-the-fly)
- [Deleting entire PHP Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534843/deleting-entire-php-class)
- [Redefining PHP function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640958/redefining-php-function)